# how do i import a blender animation into powerpoint

Tags: animation, export

I recently finished a project; I was wondering what file type should I use for the final rendered animation to import it to PowerPoint?

Comment: i don't really understand your question. And therefore my answer would be: use a movie file format which powerpoints supports. So i would search on google for "which file formats supports powerpoint" -> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-and-audio-file-formats-supported-in-powerpoint-d8b12450-26db-4c7b-a5c1-593d3418fb59

Comment: or you could also convert to animated gif?

Comment: Actually, PowerPoint supports gltf format.
<https://blog.presentationpro.com/tips-and-tricks/how-to-add-3d-animated-models-in-powerpoint/>
So you can try exporting to gltf.